# How to set or change path to Drupal 8 contact form?

Tags: 8, emails

Drupal 8 provides two default contact forms: "Personal contact form" and "Website feedback."
[image]

While "Personal contact form" is added to each user's profile by default, to "Website feedback" Drupal automatically provides a link to this form from the footer. The path of this link is "contact" by default.
How can I change the path to this contact form, where are those paths generally set and configured?

And by the way, is it possible to change the labels?

Comment: A route subscriber class. See Drupal\node\Routing\RouteSubscriber

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also needed a page at `/contact` path. With a simple custom module you can change the default routing for the contact forms.

Let's assume custom module is called: `example` and the new default for the contact forms will be `/contactform` instead of `/contact`:

**example.services.yml**

```
services:
  example.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\example\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

**src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php**

```
<?php
// Save this file as `src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php` in your module directory.

namespace Drupal\example\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Change the core's default path for `/contact` so that we can use it as an alias.
    if ($route = $collection->get('contact.site_page')) {
      $route->setPath('/contactform');
    }
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.contact_form.canonical')) {
      $route->setPath('/contactform/{contact_form}');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this was very easy to use and works as advertised. IMHO this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Each form is available at contact/{form_name}. The link on the page that you're looking at points there.

It's not possible to provide a different path, but you can manually create an alias that points to that page.

Comment: Thank you! And the labels can't be changed neither?

Comment: Which labels exactly?

Comment: Just created a form, ended with contact/kontakt... Oh really, #Drupal8?!